# Delayed closing of a javascript window

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a javascript window that displays ads for Google DFP.  I'm a beginner in javascript, and the code I have here is adapted from another ad service.

The window opens just fine on page load, and it closes when the close button is clicked, but I'd like it to close automatically after a certain amount of time (like say five seconds) has passed.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<html>
 <head>
    <style>
    .simple_overlay {
      display: none;
      z-index: 10000;
      background-color: #fff;
      width: 640px;
      height: 480px;
      border: 20px solid black;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 90px 5px #000;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 90px #000;
    }

    .simple_overlay .close {
      background-image: url https://s3.amazonaws.com/onlineads/interstitial_test/CloseWindow_shoot.png);
      position: absolute;
      right: -35px;
      top: -35px;
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 30px;
      width: 30px;
    }
    .title {
       font-weight: 20px;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/onlineads/shoot_js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/onlineads/shoot_js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
         setTimeout( function() { $("#interstitial_test").overlay({top: 200,mask: { color: "black", loadSpeed: 200, opacity: 0.5}, closeOnClick: false,load: false}); 
         setTimeout( function() {$("#interstitial_test").overlay().load();},2000);},200);
    </script>
    <title>Intestitial Test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
     <div class="simple_overlay" id="interstitial_test"> 
          <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/onlineads/shoot/Interstitial_Artwork.jpg"></img>
     </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you really need to show an ad window? I hate those, there very intrusive. That's just an opinion. Will take a look a the code for you.

Comment: If you provide a jsFiddle it will be easier.

Answer (score 1):

This will use the build in onLoad event that overlay provides. Once the overlay has been loaded the `onload` event triggers the `setTimeout` that closes the dialog.

[documentation on overlay](http://jquerytools.github.io/documentation/overlay/)

Add this to your page inside the overlay settings

```
 $("#interstitial_test").overlay(... onLoad : closeModalOverlay ...)
```

And the following function. I set the default closing time to 10 seconds

```
 function closeModalOverlay() {
     setTimeout( function() {$("#interstitial_test").overlay().close();},10000);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The subject is invalid, as you speak about window instead of a "popup"; I know it's just words; but it will help people understand your problem.

By the way, here is my suggestion :

```js
// Wait until DOM is ready
$(function(){

  // This is your Element :
  $overlay = $("#interstitial_test");
  
  // Assign the overlayJQueryStuffs
  $overlay.overlay(
    {
      top: 200,
      mask: {
        color: "black",
        loadSpeed: 200,
        opacity: 0.5
      },
      closeOnClick: false,
      load: false
    }
  );

  // Open it
  $overlay.overlay().load();

  // Close it later :
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      $overlay.overlay().close();
    },
    2000
  );
  
  
});
```

```css
.simple_overlay {
  display: none;
  z-index: 10000;
  background-color: #fff;
  /*
  width: 640px;
  height: 250px;
  */
  width: 64px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 20px solid black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 90px 5px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 90px #000;
}

.simple_overlay .close {
  background-image: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/onlineads/interstitial_test/CloseWindow_shoot.png);
  position: absolute;
  right: -35px;
  top: -35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

.title {
  font-weight: 20px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="simple_overlay" id="interstitial_test"> 
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/onlineads/shoot/Interstitial_Artwork.jpg"></img>
  </div>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
```

Hope it help.
I used this documentation to know about overlay : http://jquerytools.github.io/documentation/overlay/

---

I think @Mouser is right. I may not have understood the question.
If you want to close the popup x time after its oppening. You have to put the close function inside the onload event.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for pointing me in the right direction (and that overlay documentation.)

The answer turned out to be pretty simple; I added the following code.

```
setTimeout('$("#interstitial_test").data("overlay").close();', 10000);
```

This seems to work perfectly.

Comment: This works because the timeout is sufficient. But more general just adding this code below the line that opens the dialog is flawed. Consider the follwing situation: You have a modal dialog that loads data asynchronously, the responding server is busy and the loading takes more than 10 seconds. Before the content is loaded the dialog will be closed by your code. Using the onload event assures you that the content data is loaded before you close the window. Still I strongly advise against showing ads on this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer = 5000; // in millisecond

setTimeout(function() {
    // trigger a click on the #interstitial_test after 5 seconds.
    $('#interstitial_test').trigger('click');
}, timer);
```

Not sure if this is what you want or not. I assume you click on the #interstitial_test element to close the window.

Comment: I tried the var timer and set timeout function but it didn't seem to have any effect. Does it go above with the other functions or below the HTML?

Comment: This doesn't really take into account the jQuery tools context here plus OP seems to know how to use setTimeout